# How to respond to Bluetooth LE characteristic read request in UWP application

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to follow the examples here for creating an UWP application that will act as a Bluetooth LE peripheral:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server
but when trying to respond to the characteristic read request with request.RespondWithValue I get an exception:
System.Exception: 'The object has been committed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000001E)'

If I set a static value for the characteristic, the value is read correctly

```
 ReadParameters.StaticValue = (new byte[] { 0x21 }).AsBuffer();
```

I have tried the code both on a Windows 10 PC and Windows 10 IoT Core and get the same exception.

Is there anything else that is needed for responding to the read request?

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    GattLocalCharacteristic _readCharacteristic;
    GattServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SetupBle();
    }
    public async Task<bool> SetupBle()
    {
        GattServiceProviderResult result = await GattServiceProvider.CreateAsync(GattServiceUuids.Battery);
        if (result.Error == BluetoothError.Success)
        {
            _serviceProvider = result.ServiceProvider;
            var ReadParameters = new GattLocalCharacteristicParameters();
            ReadParameters.CharacteristicProperties = GattCharacteristicProperties.Read;
            ReadParameters.UserDescription = "Battery service";
            //ReadParameters.StaticValue = (new byte[] { 0x21 }).AsBuffer(); //if this is uncommented the static battery level value is read correctly
            GattLocalCharacteristicResult characteristicResult = await _serviceProvider.Service.CreateCharacteristicAsync(GattCharacteristicUuids.BatteryLevel, 
                ReadParameters);
            if (characteristicResult.Error != BluetoothError.Success)
            {
                return false;
            }
            _readCharacteristic = characteristicResult.Characteristic;
            _readCharacteristic.ReadRequested += _readCharacteristic_ReadRequested;
            GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters advParameters = new GattServiceProviderAdvertisingParameters
            {
                IsDiscoverable = true,
                IsConnectable = true
            };
            _serviceProvider.StartAdvertising(advParameters);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private async void _readCharacteristic_ReadRequested(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, GattReadRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var writer = new DataWriter();
        writer.WriteByte(0x21);
        var request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
        request.RespondWithValue(writer.DetachBuffer());//will throw System.Exception: 'The object has been committed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8000001E)'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment here 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/btblog/2017/05/11/welcome-to-the-new-windows-bluetooth-core-team-blog/#comment-105
and the comments here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server
the documentation was outdated and incorrect.

This code works for me:

```
    private async void _readCharacteristic_ReadRequested(GattLocalCharacteristic sender, GattReadRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
        var writer = new DataWriter();
        writer.WriteByte(0x21);
        var request = await args.GetRequestAsync();
        request.RespondWithValue(writer.DetachBuffer());
        deferral.Complete();
    }
```